# Assigning Child Records to a List from a Parent to Child Query

Tags: soql, collection, parent-to-child

Why does A work but not B? For B I receive the error: "Variable does not exist: Contacts".

A

```
List<Account> accts = [SELECT id, (SELECT id FROM CONTACTS) FROM Account];
List<Contact> cons  = new List<Contact>();
for(Account a : accts) {
    for(Contact con : a.Contacts) {
        cons.add(con);
    }
}
system.debug(accts);
system.debug(cons);
```

B

```
List<Account> accts = [SELECT id, (SELECT id FROM CONTACTS) FROM Account];
List<Contact> cons  = accts.Contacts;
system.debug(accts);
system.debug(cons);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you there's no variable called contacts on the object List. The only properties you can use are listed in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm).

This error occurs because you can't access an individual properties of a record from a list of records. If you had a single record:

```
Account acct = [SELECT id, (SELECT id FROM CONTACTS) FROM Account LIMIT 1];
```

Then, of course, you'd be allowed to assign those contacts.